# How to get 2 different colored particle systems for the same mesh?

Tags: mesh, particles, color

I want to make hexagonal Boron Nitride using Blender 2.83, which looks like the attached image.
[image]

So, I have used a "plane" mesh and turned into this structure of hexagons, which looks as below:
[image]

Now I have to add a particle system to emulate the atoms. Now the desired image has blue spheres and white spheres together. And I cannot achieve that.

I can only have the same particle system on all the vertices. If I try to select the alternate points which should be of one color in edit mode, and set up a particle system for that using a UV sphere, then all the wrong vertices end up getting that color; it doesn't go as per the pattern.

Please suggest how to deal with this problem.